Inverted hierarchy of nested dicts/lists
Considering the following dictionary:
{
  "a": {
    "b1": {
      "c": {
        "value": "c_value",
        "children": {
          "d": "d_value"
        }
      }
    },
    "b2": [
      "b2_1",
      {
        "b2_2_1": 2,
        "b2_2_2": {
          "b2_2_2_1": "b2_2_2_1_value",
          "b2_2_2_2": "b2_2_2_2_value"
        }
      },
      3
    ]
  }
}

how to reverse it such as the result is this:
{
  "d": {
    "children": {
      "c": {
        "b2": [
          3,
          {
            "b2_2_2": {
              "b2_2_2_2": "b2_2_2_2_value",
              "b2_2_2_1": "b2_2_2_1_value"
            },
            "b2_2_1": 2
          },
          "b2_1"
        ],
        "b1": {
          "a": "d_value"
        }
      }
    },
    "value": "c_value"
  }
}

I'm struggling with a recursive approach to this problem, without the need of creating a global variable to handle the results.

Presumably d is just privileged?  You seem to be picking a new root for a tree.

what have you tried so far?

@DavisHerring I guess OP wants to set the tree's new root to the first deepest non-leaf node in the old tree. There's a problem, though. In Python (and in most programming languages) dictionaries/maps/hashmaps are unordered, meaning that {"j": 3, "5": 9} == {"5": 9, "j": 3} is true. Because of this, you cannot determine algorithmically which same-depth node "comes first" and the choice of d as the new root node instead of b2_2_2_2 or b2_2_2_1 is totally arbitrary. If you want the node order to matter, you should use another data structure. A vector-based tree, maybe?

You are asking for a very specific transformation of your original dictionary. This means that you need to define a custom transformation for exactly this case. Here is how you should do this, but note that any new changes you want to make need a new way of doing it. This solution teaches you the way you should reason:
import json

def custom_transform(d):
    transformed = {
        "d": {
            "children": {
                "c": {
                    "b2": [
                        d["a"]["b2"][2],  
                        {
                            "b2_2_2": {
                                "b2_2_2_2": d["a"]["b2"][1]["b2_2_2"]["b2_2_2_2"],
                                "b2_2_2_1": d["a"]["b2"][1]["b2_2_2"]["b2_2_2_1"]
                            },
                            "b2_2_1": d["a"]["b2"][1]["b2_2_1"]
                        },
                        d["a"]["b2"][0]  
                    ],
                    "b1": {
                        "a": d["a"]["b1"]["c"]["children"]["d"]
                    }
                }
            },
            "value": d["a"]["b1"]["c"]["value"]
        }
    }
    return transformed

original_dict = {
    "a": {
        "b1": {
            "c": {
                "value": "c_value",
                "children": {
                    "d": "d_value"
                }
            }
        },
        "b2": [
            "b2_1",
            {
                "b2_2_1": 2,
                "b2_2_2": {
                    "b2_2_2_1": "b2_2_2_1_value",
                    "b2_2_2_2": "b2_2_2_2_value"
                }
            },
            3
        ]
    }
}

transformed_dict = custom_transform(original_dict)
print(json.dumps(transformed_dict, indent=4))

which gives you your expected output:
{
    "d": {
        "children": {
            "c": {
                "b2": [
                    3,
                    {
                        "b2_2_2": {
                            "b2_2_2_2": "b2_2_2_2_value",
                            "b2_2_2_1": "b2_2_2_1_value"
                        },
                        "b2_2_1": 2
                    },
                    "b2_1"
                ],
                "b1": {
                    "a": "d_value"
                }
            }
        },
        "value": "c_value"
    }
}

